# Trying to create a ROS Kinetic Node which depends on python 3.6 but Kinetic supports only python version 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, ros, tensorflow2

I am trying to use a model.h5 (witch I created on  python3,tensorflow2) on  a node on ROS kinetic (ubuntu 16.04) to predict the steering angle of  a turtlebot3 (running on gazebo7) after receiving a frame/image. The incompatibility of ROS with any other python versions takes me to a deadend since I tried everything I could think of. I tried installing a venv of python 3, but as soon as I change the python alternative or the script's python version ROS won't run and none of the other possible solutions that I found online worked for me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use ROS Noetic, which does support python 3?

Comment: My uni's team works on a project on ROS Kinetic and I would like to actively participate on that research. I may could use noetic to have results for research purposes, the matter is, that I also tried to install ros noetic with no success, since I get an "unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full" whitch also is an unsolved issue as far as I can tell.. Thanks for your immediate response!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run a ros node with Python3 under Kinetic. As mentioned in a comment Noetic would be your best option if you need Python3, however, you cannot run Noetic on 16.04; it would need to be 20.04. If both python3 and Kinetic/16.04 nodes are absolutely needed you'll have to use another way to communicate. The best way to do this is most likely abstracting out the ros parts from your python3 scripts and having it communicate via TCP/UDP socket.

Comment: thanks for your response also, I went with the ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 option. Everything seems to work fine and the whole env is user friendlier, the gazebo simulator seems to run smoother also.